Orthogonal projections and minimization problems
Consider the following problem of finding a polynomial $u$ with real coefficients and degree at most $5$ that on the interval $[-\pi,\pi]$ approximates $\sin(x)$ as well possible, in the sense that
$$
\int\limits_{-\pi}^{\pi} |\sin(x)-u(x)|^{2} dx
$$
In effet, let $v\in C[\pi,\pi]$ be the function defined by $v(x)=\sin(x)$. Let $U$ denote the subspace of $C[\pi,\pi]$ consisting of the polynomials with real coefficients and degree at most $5$. Our problem can now be reformulated as follows: find $u \in U$ such that $\|v-u\|$ as small possible. In light of Linear Algebra, the function $u$ sucht $\|v-u\|$ as small possible is $P_{U}v$ (orthogonal projection onto $U$).
According to my calculations, I didn't obtain the Taylor polynomial expression for $\sin(x)$
, which is what I was expecting. Therefore, I wonder what the correct basis would be to orthonormalize? and if I used the correct inner product. Any tips?

You are not using the trignometric functions as basis?

You are using the correct polynomial basis (not orthogonalized yet), but the Taylor series is not optimal. Taylor series is optimal in the limit as the neighborhood approaches the expansion point. You are asked for an expansion optimal about $[-\pi,\pi]$.
